# What's the difference between the ItemTapped and the ItemSelected event on a ListView in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

A `ListView` in Xamarin.Forms has two events, which seem to be exactly the same: [ItemTapped](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=E%3aXamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemTapped) and [ItemSelected](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=E%3aXamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemSelected)

There isn't really any documentation about these, so what exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ItemSelected` is a **state** while `ItemTapped` is a **motion event**. All views can be **tapped** and if I remember correctly all views can be selected (or at least activated there is a subtle difference), the two don't have to go together but they usually do.

For example you'd have an item's selected state toggled each time a **tapped** motion event has occurred. Once again just to make it more clear you can associate the changes of the selected state to whatever you need whether it's a motion event like **tapping** or **long pressing** or **double tapping** and so on or to some other event or logic.

Hope it helps and good luck!

Comment: How can you implement a long press in a list view with xamarin.forms?

Answer (score 13):

`ItemTapped` should occur every time you **click** on an item, while `ItemSelected` every time the selected item **has changed**.

Basically

- tapping two times the same item should fire two times `ItemTapped`, and only once `ItemSelected`
- tapping two times, on different items, should fire `ItemTapped` two times, and `ItemSelected` two times

Comment: Weird, ItemSelected is fired twice in the first case for me.

Comment: The implementation may change of course with different versions, and platforms. I remember also a 1.x not always firing ItemTapped for Windows Phone. You should raise a bug in bugzilla

Answer (score 1):

ItemSelected occurs first.
ItemTapped occurs second.

Answer (score 1):

One major difference worth noting is how they work when the `SelectionMode="None"`

```
<ListView ... SelectionMode="None" />
```

When set to "None"...the `ItemSelect` event will not fire and `SelectedItem` property remains `null`.

> But `ItemTapped` events will continue to fire as expected.

[ListView interactivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity)

Answer (score 0):

I think ItemSelected is when you use the DataTemplate for your items.