# Xamarin Forms ListView ItemSelected functionality

Tags: android, listview, async-await, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Here is a function that gets called when an item gets selected from a `ListView`:

```
async void detail_clicked(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e){
    if (e.SelectedItem == null) {
            return;
    }
    Detail selected = (Detail)e.SelectedItem;
    order_vm.List_of_details.Add(selected);
    await DisplayAlert ("Item Added", 
        String.Format ("{0} added to cart.", selected.detail_name), "Okay");
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
}
```

I added this function using the `ItemSelected` event handler

```
details_list.ItemSelected += detail_clicked;
```

The first time I click on the Item, the `DisplayAlert` pops up. After the first click, the `DisplayAlert` inside `detail_clicked` no longer pops up. But the other code inside the handler does get called.

Anyone know how to fix this issue? Is it something I am not understanding about event handlers? Is it something about await/async?

Comment: Have you tried using the `ItemTapped` event for the `ListView` instead? As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27453218/2399772), there are differences in the implementation of the two events. I normally always use `ItemTapped` when simply listening for events where the user taps on an element in the `ListView` that I wish to do something with (e.g. navigating to a new page for editing the item, opening a display alert for deleting the item, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I tried the same process except with attaching this function to the ````ItemTapped```` event and I had the same results. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The DisplayAlert might be running on a different thread. Try wrapping Display Alert in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`. You can ready about that [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/).

Answer (score 0):

Please check again without async on method and await on DisplayAlert().

Answer (score 0):

Use this following code. It will helps you.

```
private void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        {

            return;

        }

        listView.SelectedItem = null;

        DisplayAlert("Alert", e.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Ok");

    }
```